# Where Should Rendering Logic Live Parent or Child?

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent component which renders a comment. A child of this component is a delete comment component. I only want to render the delete comment component if a user has a specific role.

My question is where should this logic live in the parent or the child?

My thoughts are which component is responsible for managing the permissions to do with deleting a comment? Is it the responsibility of the delete component or the component which is composed of a delete comment.

I went away from the parent component having to know anything about permissions to delete comments, it just knows that it is composed of a delete component, but not the internal details of how that works, all that logic is encapsulated in the delete comment component.

But I have had feedback on this approach questioning why render a component which is specifically to delete a comment, if you can't ever delete a comment.

Code snippets:

delete comment component has logic like:

```
  this.props.userGroups.includes(DELETE_COMMENTS) ? <a onClick={this.deleteComment(deleteComment)}>Remove comment</a> : null
```

and the parent simply has:

```
     <DeleteComment />
```

with no logic on checking if the user can delete a comment

or should it be more like:

```
  this.props.userGroups.includes(DELETE_COMMENTS) ? <DeleteComment /> : null
```

Comment: I would have answered to the "feedback" with rendering a `<CommentActions />` component which would be concerned whether the user has permission, lest the container unnecessarily renders a delete component or delete component is concerned with any of the permissions. (Not fixing your problem, just a remark)

Comment: As the name suggests, components should only `React` to flowing data. Putting the rendering decision inside the component itself is an anti-pattern.